# Design approaches to read/write different version of same config file

Tags: c++, xml, qt, design-patterns, user-interface

In our project we got an application that uses an external configuration file (say server.xml). Now we need to design a setup tool GUI in C++/QT to read/edit such configuration file and it should be able to handle all the different versions of such file. The user will choose the file version and then proceed with the editing. From one version to another doesn't change too much, maybe there is a new xml tag, a tag with a different name or in a different position.

What's the best design approach to do so? We are planning to go for a standard MVC design pattern but how to deal with all the different configuration versions without rewriting the same GUI code again n again?

Here the sample config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Server_configuration ver="11">
  <core>
    <enable-tms>true</enable-tms>
    <enable-gui-messages>true</enable-gui-messages>
    <waiting-for-config-timeout>10000</waiting-for-config-timeout>
    <remoting>
      <port>50000</port>
      <join-timeout>5000</join-timeout>
      <ismultithread>true</ismultithread>
      <maxconcurrentrequests>20</maxconcurrentrequests>
    </remoting>
  </core>
  <content>
    <ftp>
      <ip>192.168.0.227</ip>
      <port>21</port>
      <userid>******</userid>
      <passwd>******</passwd>
    </ftp>
    <library>
      <ip>192.168.0.227</ip>
      <port>50023</port>
    </library>
    <local>
      <asset-root>/assetroot</asset-root>
      <kdm-expiration-warning>172800000</kdm-expiration-warning>
    </local>
    <hula-store-daemon>
      <ip>127.0.0.1</ip>
      <port>5567</port>
    </hula-store-daemon>
  </content>
</Server_configuration>
```

Comment: Either disable or hide GUI element that are invalid for the file, or make fully dynamic GUI where only the common elements are there by default and all other added when needed. Also, it might be to late now, but having a version tag in the file will make the version-selection by the user not needed. It will add a new dimension of user-reported bugs by having it, and then the user selects the wrong version. If it's not possible to add a version tag, then try to autodetect it by checking what tags are in the file.

Comment: The best design IMHO is to make the GUI static. Always use the most up to date GUI and have a tool to convert old data(config file) into the updated version. Even this idea is a nightmare for maintenance. What type of config information do you have to save that will change a GUI? Can you give an example?

Comment: Version attributes are the way to go. You may also find it helpful to have internal configuration abstraction classes that are capable of translating between config file versions and the interfaces expected by the application. So long as an abstraction layer can translate between and older and a newer version of the config file, it maybe possible to chain them and so handle configurations of any age. This depends entirely on your config schemas however; some systems may be too awkward to handle in this way.

Comment: @Rook: your approach seems to be promising... I'll add the server.xml config file to the post

Comment: I added the config file... check it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is no means a drop in solution but I here are some things to do/consider.  Every situation will differ.

- Have an explicit version identifier in your config files.  Fingerprinting them is a real (error prone) pain.
- Consider having a tool that will update from version to version.  It will be easier than reading old versions and trying to apply them.

  - I may be easier to do every version step individually but this can make the conversions less "lossless".  A happy hybrid is to do minor updates from version to version but have "checkpoint" major upgrades that will jump right to the latest (or the latest "checkpoint").  This is kinda like [incremental backups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_backup) with full backup snapshots every once and a while.
  - Keep the user informed.  A sysadmin won't be happy if you are changing his settings.  You might want to make the process interactive or put comments into the file of every added/moved/removed setting.  I would also recommend keeping removed settings in some section of the file for user reference. (Put a note why they are there as well).
- Backup the old file.  Your script will crash and it will eat data.  Do something like naming the current file `${oldname}.old-${ver}~`.  Saving the settings in a different section of the file won't always be enough and this will save your users a lot of heartache.

Answer (score 1):

Versioning should always be designed as robust and as simple as possible.  It is crucial for you to determine whether each version of your application must be compatible with each version of the setup tool (which is rare), or whether you can, for example, meet your needs if any newer setup tool works with any same or older application, but not vice versa.

**One way compatibility**

One possibility to design for the latter is to add a version attribute to the XML file but try to keep it at the same fixed value forever by always only changing the structure and semantics of the XML file in backward compatible ways.  For example, adding an element is backward compatible as long as the setup tool can interpret its absence the same way both the old setup tool and the application would behave.  It does not hurt that the new setup tool always writes an (equivalent) value to the new element, because two-way compatibility with the old application is not required.

Once the day comes when you cannot maintain backward compatibility on input, you just change the value of the version attribute and start special casing it in the setup tool.

If you validate the XML against an XSD, notice that XSD can actually do one frequently useful thing for you: assign default attribute values.  This way, your setup tool's source code may not even actually notice that the underlying document was missing a recently added attribute!

**Two way compatibility**

Strict versioning is needed.  A schema definition (XSD, RelayNG,...) should be defined for each version of the XML file and the file should be validated against it both when it is read by the setup tool, written by the setup tool, or read by the application.  The schema definition may be identical for several consecutive versions, if the interpretation of the same XML has changed, so when in doubt, always increase the version number.

Do what you can educating everyone that they cannot just edit the latest schema and do away with that.  Unreliable versioning is worse than no versioning.